# How close to the unit norm is $\|Ux\|$ where $U$ is orthonormal and $\|x\|_2=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $U\in \mathbb{R}^{r \times d}$ and orthonormal matrix, i.e., $U^TU = I_{d \times d}$, and $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ a unit vector, i.e., $\|x\|_2 = 1$, can we make any deduction on how close to the unit the vector $Ux\in \mathbb{R}^r$ is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Orthonormal linear transformations preserve norms:

$$\|Ux\|_2^2 = (Ux)^T(Ux) = x^TU^TUx = x^Tx = \|x\|_2^2.$$

Note that this works precisely because your orthonormality is $U^TU = I$ i.e., the rectangular matrix has orthonormal columns, not rows.